# Difference between printk and pr_info

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, printk

What's the exact difference between `printk` and `pr_info` functions ? And under what conditions, should I choose one over the another ?

Comment: @CL. Yes, my bad.

Comment: All those are equivalent except debug one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [kernel's printk.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5-rc5/source/include/linux/printk.h#L527) has:

```c
#define pr_info(fmt,arg...) \
    printk(KERN_INFO fmt,##arg)
```

Just like the name, `pr_info()` is `printk()` with the `KERN_INFO` priority.

Comment: Actually `#define pr_info(fmt, ...)  eprintf(0, verbose, pr_fmt(fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: Exception is `pr_debug()` vs. `printk(KERN_DEBUG)` and all derivatives.

Answer (score 11):

When looking specifically at `pr_info`, the definition will in turn use `printk(KERN_INFO ...` (as mentioned in barcelona_delpy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243185/difference-between-printk-and-pr-info/42243429#42243429)); however, the answer's source snippet appears to exclude the format wrapper `pr_fmt(fmt)` (as mentioned by LPs [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243185/difference-between-printk-and-pr-info#comment71646428_42243429)).

---

**The difference** to why you may use `pr_info` over `printk(KERN_INFO ...` is the custom formatting you can set. If you wish to prefix your messages in your module with `printk`, a method is to explicitly add your prefix on each line:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "mymodule: hello there\n");
// outputs "mymodule: hello there"
```

or:

```
printk(KERN_INFO KBUILD_MODNAME " hello there\n");
// outputs "mymodule: hello there"
```

However, if you use `pr_info` (and other `pr_*` functions), you can re-define the format and simply use `pr_info` without additional work:

```
... (includes)
#ifdef pr_fmt
#undef pr_fmt
#endif
#define pr_fmt(fmt) KBUILD_MODNAME ": " fmt

...
{
    ...
    pr_err("hello there\n");
    // outputs "mymodule: hello there" (assuming module is named 'mymodule')
    ...
}
...
```

See also:

- [Kernel.org | Printing kernel messages](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html#printing-kernel-messages)
- [printk implementation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/printk.h#n284)
- [lwn.net | The perils of pr_info()](https://lwn.net/Articles/487437/)